# why is mathjax not working with https

Tags: https, web2py, mathjax

I have made a site http://gurleen.pythonanywhere.com. 
There are some issues

- The connection is not secure, so how do i make it secure
- When i use https, mathjax does not seem to work, why?

Comment: are you at least able to get your site running on https? you can obtain free ssl cert from Let's Encrypt. Once you have done that, you should use https version of MathJax library from cdnjs.com.

Comment: https://gurleen.pythonanywhere.com works but mathjax does not works on it. In the case of http://gurleen.pythonanywhere.com mathjax works. I am using the https version of cdnjs for both the cases. I'm new to this https part so please tell me where i'm going wrong

Comment: In your https enabled site, change mathjax src from `http` to `https`

Comment: thanks man it worked. Now how do i make it default so that it opens with https only and not http

Comment: you need to 301 redirect any http requests to https. just google it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your https enabled site, I think you need to change from `http` to `https` when you add MathJax library from cdnjs:

**change from**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js">
```

**to**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js">
```

Here is a full example of MathJax that should work on your https enabled site:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/config/TeX-MML-AM_CHTML.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>$$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$$</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your links work but they seem different from those from the official site, which don't work.  I wonder why...

Answer (score 0):

Also, web2py can redirect all your traffic to HTTPS by calling `request.requires_https()` at the top of your model.